# Create List<T> instance from Iterator<T>

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Anyone know if there is a standard way to create a List from an Iterator instance?

Comment: you can't create list from Iterator, you can create List and Iterator over it's elements.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to create a `List` from an `Iterator`. It's like creating an array from just an index!

Comment: If your iterator has already had its 'next()' function called, you will never be able to retrieve previous elements.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 And if you add each element from the iterator to a new list, you're creating a list from an iterator...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tend towards [Guava's `Lists.newArrayList(Iterator)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-java.util.Iterator-) because I generally have Guava as a dependency, and it already exists.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Iterator` to get every element and add it to a `List`.

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

while(iter.hasNext()) { // iter is of type Iterator<String>
    list.add(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did, but I was hoping for some magic method out there to help me out :)

Comment: If you wanted magic methods, you should have used third-party libraries.

Comment: In Java 8 you can replace the loop with `iterator.forEachRemaining(list::add);`.

Answer (score 5):

I had this need, and as a user of Apache Commons, this is what I did:

```
IteratorUtils.toList(iterator);
```

Javadoc here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils.html#toList(java.util.Iterator)

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can use these ways (while verbose enough):

```
Iterator<String> iterator = ...;
List<String> list = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
Iterator<String> iterator = ...;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // or LinkedList() if more relevant (adding being faster for LinkedList)
iterator.forEachRemaining(list::add);
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like the following:

```
public T List<T> listFromIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {

List<T> result = new LinkedList<T>();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    result.add(iterator.next());
  }

}
```

One thing to note is that if the iterator is not at the beginning of your structure, you have no way of retrieving previous elements.

If you have the collection that the iterator is from, you can create a list by using a constructor that takes a collection. ex: the `LinkedList` constructor:

```
LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way that I convert from List to Iterator and vice versa.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(); 
// add elements to the array list 
arrayList.add("C"); 
arrayList.add("A"); 
arrayList.add("E"); 
arrayList.add("B"); 
arrayList.add("D"); 
arrayList.add("F"); 

// use iterator to display contents of arrayList
System.out.print("Original contents of arrayList: "); 
Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator(); 
ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {

    Object element = iterator.next(); 
    arrayList2.add(element);
    System.out.print(element + " ");

}
```